# How to set up second screen in iMac 2017 with macOS 10.12.6 Sierra?

Tags: display, macos, imac, screen, video-adapter

I have a new iMac 4k 21.5" (2017) running under macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and featuring 2 Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports for the connection to additional displays.

I'm attempting to connect this Mac to my 6 years old Samsung HD TV (32" 1080p (UE32C)) but with no luck. My TV has 4 HDMI ports, port 1 is connected to Apple TV and works quite well, the rest 3 ports had been used to hook up my Mac over an [EZQuest](http://ezq.com/blog/ezquest-news-room/usb-c-to-hdmi-4k-adapter/) cable.

I supposed that connection process should be trivial, you only have to connect the cable to the mac and to the TV than open system config tool and set up monitor in the screen config section but I failed. I have only got the black screen on the TV and second screen doesn't appear in the macOS config utility.

I would appreciate if someone suggest me where is the root of problem except the broken cable obviously.

Comment: Except for a cable issue, I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem finally, today I bought cheap Lenovo adapter and it works well. Previously unfair ad drove me to make the wrong decision to buy incompatible adapter. My brand new [EZQuest](http://ezq.com/blog/ezquest-news-room/usb-c-to-hdmi-4k-adapter/) cable working well with old MacBook 12" 2015 refuses to work with iMac 21.5" 4K 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware issue.

Try finding the cause by testing it on either Thunderbolt 3 port on your iMac, on all the HDMI ports on the TV (especially test it with port 1 that you have already identified is working), test with a different HDMI cable - and ultimately test with a different adapter if possible.

In my experience the setups where you have an adapter and then an HDMI cable are more error-prone than those where you have a cable directly from Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C connector) to HDMI.

Comment: Sorry for delaying I was in the longlasting business trip and didn't have access to my Mac. I have the cable connecting the iMac straightforward from the Thunderbolt 3 (USB Type-C) to the HDMI port on the TV without extra adapters. And I've reset NVRAM and SMC but with no luck. The only option I've not tested yet is another cable.

Comment: Maybe it's a matter so I want to mention here that when I connect ny Mac to the TV it displays the message on the black screen telling me that resolution isn't supported.

Comment: Quite important information :-) You have selected a too high resolution for the external monitor. In the System Prefences under Display, choose to Gather Windows so that you can change the preferences for the TV on the main display. Set it to a lower resolution and hopefully things will start working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have to admit that macOS doesn't detect second monitor at all consequently Gather Windows button unavailable in Display preferences

Comment: Sounds very much like a cable failure :-) Try with a different cable.

Comment: I have to agree it seems to me too that the cable failure is the very cause. Nevertheless it's odd thing because the cable is absolutely new brand one and is advertised as completely compatible with Mac's Thunderbolt 3. Could you point me to another model please?

Comment: New cables can be defective just as old cables. Get it replaced where you bought it.

Comment: I've tested the cable with another Mac recently and I have to say it works fine with old MacBook 12" featuring Thunderbolt 3 port. Additionally I've tested the iMac's USB 3.1 Type-C port (the same port as Thunderbolt 3) with flash stick and it works good as well. So obviously cable is OK maybe the reason is macOS itself?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the problem is macOS. It wouldn't be wise to spend time on that assumption. Check the same Mac and cable with a different TV then. I'm a bit concerned about your third party "adapter cable" - some of these have been known to be flaky earlier. For example only working with old Thunderbolt chipsets or similar. If you know someone that have the Apple adapter, you could give that a try. I have used both the Apple and Dell adapters without any problems.

Comment: It seems to me that you have never tried attaching an external display to a Mac - therefore let me detail how it normally works: You plugin the HDMI cable to the TV. You plugin the other end of the cable to the Mac. After a few seconds the TV will display a mirror of what's on your Mac. If you want, you can then use System Preferences > Displays to customize the setup to choose extended desktop, different screen resolutions, etc.

Comment: I go this way exactly as you wrote step by step but I get only error message about inappropriate resolution on the TV screen and system doesn't detect monitor at all. Beside of this I've checked it with another monitor with the same result. It seems to me the last resort is to check another cable maybe Apple's one

Comment: Sounds like a cable failure...